# How to send and receive data over a serial port from a dialog box

Tags: c#, multithreading, dialog

I have a c# application on Windows (IDE is Visual Studio with .Net Framework 4.8) that communicates with a device under test (DUT) over a serial port.  There are parameters that need to be configured on the DUT before the test begins.  I have a form created that I call with the code below:

```
using ( bleAddressForm = new BLE_addr_form( ComPort ) )
{
   var result = bleAddressForm.ShowDialog();
   if ( result == DialogResult.OK )
   {
      // Save the new address
      bleControl.SetAddress(bleAddressForm.txtBox_addr.Text);
      btnBLEcontrol.Text = bleControl.GetAddress();
   }
}
```

The dialog box needs to query the DUT and receive responses to configure it for the test.  The problem is I do not know how to process the received serial port data.  The serial port data is normally processed in a routine called port_DataReceived() that is called by the system when data is received on the serial port (and yes I know this is problematic and not always reliable).  This call is setup with the code below:

```
ComPort.DataReceived += new System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);
```

I have a weak understanding of Threads on Windows (I’m new to c# but have 30+ years of embedded C and Linux experience) and suspect what is happening is the bleAddressForm is in a new thread and the thread that created it (and has the serial data processing code) is not run until bleAddressForm exits with either the “Ok” or “Cancel” button being clicked to cause this.Close() to be called.

The code is dozens of files and thousands of lines so I don’t think it wise to post all of it.

Any suggestions on how to have a dialog box send and receive serial port data?

My current thought is to close the serial port before creating the dialog box and instead passing in an already opened SerialPort I pass it the serial port name as a String and open the serial port within the dialog box code.  This would require replicating all the serial port handling done in the code that called the dialog box and just seems to be an inelegant solution.